# 4, 2, 4, 2305843009213693952, ? - an original number sequence

Tags: number-sequence, sequence

Here is the sequence:

4, 2, 4, 2305843009213693952, ?

Source: My brain (as it was invented by me. I also attempted to search if someone else created this, but I was unable to find)

Hint 1:

> These values are computed as values from an function f(x). Given that f(x1) = 4, f(x2) = 2, f(x3) = 4, f(x4) = 2305843009213693952 then  f(x5) = f(x4+1) = f(x3+2) = f(x2+3) = f(x1+4) = ?

Hint 2: (still minor)

> function is a power of 2.

Hint 3: (final big revealing hint)

> function contains factorial operation

I added the answer below.

Comment: Is the last number correct or did you use JavaScript? :)

Comment: @Lukas Rotter maybe both? :-)

Comment: Oh, it was edited already ... is the correct answer $2^{2556}$?

Comment: The four terms are *rot13(cbjref bs gjb naq jura V ybbxrq hc gung frdhrapr bs cbjref va brvf gurer jrer gjb cbffvoyr frevrf sentzragf, jvgu n qvssrerag arkg grez va rnpu, fb gjb cbffvoyr nafjref)*, which goes to show there is **not enough information**: the answer might be anything.

Comment: @WeatherVane I looked this up on oeis and I didn't find anything

Comment: @WOWOW that depends on *what* you looked up.

Comment: @WeatherVane What _exactly_ did you look up?

Comment: @WOWOW I looked up what I said I looked up in the first comment.

Comment: Sorry, but 'extremely vague with barely enough info to get a hint of an idea' does not a 'tough' number sequence puzzle make. Once upon a time, an associate of Richard Feynman was making a presentation on training a computer to solve number sequence puzzles. As examples, he showed some number sequences to the audience and asked them to figure out the next number. Feynman, who was in the front row, would always shout out "Nine!". Here one could always say that this number sequence repeats +2,-2,+2,+2305843009213693948,-23058430092136943.

Comment: Right now it's just a 'guess what I'm thinking' puzzle.

Comment: Aren't all the puzzle like that? even IQ 180 puzzle posted by NSE? They are all "Guess what I'm thiking" but unlike those puzzles, I accept all the solutions that have a logic. z100 provided a 2nd solution to my problem which I find it acceptable. You are free to find your own solution, or to use my hints and find my solution. All solutions are acceptable as long as they have a well defined logic.

Comment: I fail to see how 4, 2, 4 become +2 -2 +2. So I don't see any logic in your solution.

Answer (score 3):

It could be
27081263142182923706327232687195658070428245269515847892301960409193603497079267429599499960528359960959528695040131823079640006913802719873131394451528651722752913514197569737603884522462215747430864717556563140418952465231370340858980232933674360496286095284732772649814959911715515546312122231773894817720740695859908220802793394046073943338660699378330812357275863482151108777140894729391708472075600409086868809915846356388672978929559319374966287312445357447235529173652701857494948733493186158564161003131718804333769636805443818453958741618817549196610744732648045052782615690023473893204676535902778901240119761679691148400270562703168660927014740991948024946255142681294901882285976068566168233454182356583836635726153292066470424002453289440127311808284327936

It is equal to:

> $2^{2556}$

> https://oeis.org/A084659 multiplied by 2. Number of labeled claw-free cubic graphs on 2n nodes (not necessarily connected). OEIS: $1,  0,  1,  60,  2555$, increased by $1$: $2, 1, 2, 61, 2556$, powers of $2$ eq. OP: $4, 2, 4, 2^{61}, 2^{2556}$

Comment: @z100 you got what I missed: rot13(gur frdhrapr bs bar yrff guna rnpu cbjre bs gjb).

Comment: @Weather Vane thx

Comment: @z100, could you please update your explanation? I still don't understand your answer

Comment: 1, 0, 1, 60  from OEIS --> 2,1,2,61 from OP

Comment: In other words 2^(n+1)

Comment: the array as powers of 2 is: 2 1 2 61, which is quite different from: 1 60 2555 from what I read regarding "Numbers of labeled cubic claw-free graphs" on table 2 on the site https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220533150_Counting_Claw-Free_Cubic_Graphs

Now if that array that you proposed is actually 1 0 1 60 2555 then it is nice that you found a second solution for my problem (different from the one I had in mind). But from what I saw it is only 1 60 2555 and not 1 0 1 60 2555.

Comment: See at the top of Table 2, there are initial values 1 and 0 for 0th and 1st H.

Answer (score 2):

Solution:

> f(N) = 2^(2^N! - N).

> f(0) = 2^(2^(0!) - 0) = 4 (0! = 1)

> f(1) = 2^(2^(1!) - 1) = 2 (1! = 1)

> f(2) = 2^(2^(2!) - 2) = 4 (2! = 2)

> f(3) = 2^(2^(3!) - 3) = 2^61 (3! = 6, 2^6 = 64)

> f(4) = 2^(2^(4!) - 4) = 2^(16777216 - 4) = 2^16777212